# Automation anywhere drop-down menu error

Tags: drop-down-menu, rpa, automationanywhere

Hello I tried to use MWC function in AAE to pick the correct position form drop-down menu but I am receiving following error: 
[AAE Drop-down menu Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fDqX.jpg)
[Drop-down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJKJZ.jpg)

Could you help me and point what I am doing wrong ?
There is something wrong with format of "Text to set" how it supposed to look like.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary solution that I have found is to use object cloning for clicking selected drop-down menu and then chose the right option with Manage web recorder. If somebody have an idea how to do it more optimally I will appreciate answer!!

Comment: Yes, you have used the right approach by going for Object cloning over Windows control simply because Object cloning lets you have increased control over the objects and their properties.
But I would suggest you use Object cloning and chose the right option from within the Object Properties rather than using Web recorder after that.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the second image ([Drop-down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJKJZ.jpg)), this application shows the **PO Actions** in an **expand-contract** fashion, not as a **drop-down**. Automation Anywhere can work with a drop-down menu that is actually of type **HTML Dropdown**. So, the **Select Item By Text** activity won't work with your target application.

Your workaround is actually the correct way to implement this automation. Also, as Clint commented, use the Object Properties wisely to ensure that automation works every time.
For example, avoid HTML element like **ID, Height, Width, Coordinates**, etc.
Instead, rely on matching **HTML Inner Text** to select the same option every time (for example, **Release PO** in this case).